# Is there any advantage for Entity Framework generic repository?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am new with the entity framework architecture. I have try to make some sample code with the `edmx` file, but now I want to write the generic code for the entity framework, and I want to know that any advantage of to write this generic code. Because there are so many methods which is already provided by the entity frameworks objects.

Please let me know your answer, because your answer will become more helpful in my new project development.

Comment: You mean except that it is redundant and the classic generic repository is an ANTIPATTERN as it is a dead end destroying your database side Efficiency?

Comment: not sure if there are real benefits in comparison with a database-first setup. DB-first gives you the ability to keep your objects in sync with the datamodel without writing any code. In a DB first setup you can add logic in a partial class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're new to the entity framework architecture then you can start it from Code-First development.

What is **Code-First** ?

You can,

1. Develop without ever having to open a designer or define an XML mapping file
2. Define your model objects by simply writing “plain old classes (poco)” with no base classes  required
3. Use a “convention over configuration” approach that enables database persistence without explicitly configuring anything
4. Optionally override the convention-based persistence and use a fluent code API to fully customize the persistence mapping

You can follow very good light weigh [**MVC Music Store Application Here**](http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/)

You can get more knowledge about [**Code-First Development with Entity Framework 4 Here**](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx)

I hope this will help to you.